# Why is my boot folder empty?

Tags: boot, command-line, dual-boot, chromebook

I'm trying to learn, with the ultimate goal of running a significant amount of my digital life through Linux. Right now I know nothing. My deck is a Dell Chromebook 13.

After enabling developer mode, I downloaded Crouton from github.com/dnschneid/crouton.

Then I opened the shell and did the following: `sudo sh ~/Downloads/crouton -e -t -xfce`

This appeared to work. I was prompted to create a password and encryption key, and then to create username and password for Ubuntu. Good.

When I do `lsb_release -a` I see I have Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS (xenial).

I'm using Shotts's book *The Linux Command Line* to figure out what I'm doing. Everything seems good until I start poking around directories and find only the following in /boot:

When I do `ls -l`: "total 0"

When I do `ls -a`: ". .."

Shotts indicates there should be quite a bit more there. I apologize for my lack of knowledge. I'm just trying to get a light, workable version of Linux dual-booted on my deck so I can teach myself a bit. Any advice, keeping in mind my ignorance, would be grand.

Comment: Try `ls /boot/*` and see if files are listed. In order to boot Ubuntu in the first place there must be files there. Additionally my first go around I also tried encryption but that didn't last and I reinstalled soon without it. Encryption comes with overhead on your part to administer and puts overhead on the machine.

Comment: When I do `ls /boot/*` I see the following: "ls: cannot access `/boot/*`: No such file or directory." Should I wipe everything and then go back into developer mode, or is there a simpler way to start clean? Would you recommend I do everything the same but simply omit the `-e` option, or can you suggest a lighter, faster, more stable distribution? Thanks.

Comment: try `sudo ls /boot/`.

Comment: Erkin, that gives me no result. I tried `sudo ls -a /boot/` too, and I get ". .."

Comment: @palaver I'm not familiar with **developer mode** nor the **-e** option. Most of us simply download the Ubuntu 16.04 Live USB/DVD and boot with it to "Try Ubuntu" first and after success to "Install Ubuntu". With this method you can still choose to encrypt or not encrypt data. Again I found not encrypting data kept life simple.

Comment: **Crouton** stands for *ChRomium Os Universal chrooT envirONment* and I'm not sure we even support that on this site....

Comment: Thanks, WinE. I'd like to be able to run it alongside Chrome OS, at least until I get my feet under me w/r/t Linux. If I ran Ubuntu from USB, would it be easy for me to flip back to Chrome? Can you recommend a site that gives reliable instructions? Thanks.

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix that been said I would think his filesystem might be different from regular Ubuntu...

Comment: Search for that folder with `sudo find / -type d -iname "boot*"`, and see if you can locate it. It will take a bit of time depending on the size of your system

Comment: @palaver At this stage any opinions I render would be pure speculation which is  a disservice to both of us. I suggest logging into Google support forums for specific advise on running Debian/Ubuntu within Chromium OS.

Comment: @George, `sudo find / -type d -iname "boot*"` led me to /usr/lib/systemd/boot, which has a directory "efi" containing two executable files "for MS Windows." I think I will look at Google support forums, as WinEunuuchs2Unix suggests. I feel out of my depth already, and all I want is to have a stable distro to play around with.

Answer (score 0):

Well. Google support wasn't very helpful, as they basically just say "if you're using developer mode, you're on your own." Reddit (/r/Crouton) produced a reasonable answer:

> When running in Crouton, the instance isn't a VM, it's sharing the kernel with ChromeOS...it does not do a traditional boot.

This from PaintDrinkingPete. I don't know what a VM is exactly, but dual booting would complicate the whole idea of boot directories, wouldn't it? Good enough for me, for now.

If you're here too, PDP, cheers mate.